# Problem with use \url - metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, urls

I try to write an article in LaTeX using texmaker on ubuntu.
I use many packages including:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
```

But when I use `\url{something}` I get a font problem:

```
! Font T1/pcr/m/n/12=pcrr8t at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not     found
.
<to be read again>
relax
l.33 \url{test}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
```

Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I took your preamble and added `\usepackage{url}`, which worked without problems.

Comment: Answer is simple. I use these comand:
sudo apt-get install abntex
sudo apt-get install texmaker
and sudo apt-get  install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended texmaker

this helped me